# Oracle Apex Internal error, Could not validate caller for user "" when parsing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper, oracle-apex-19.2

I'm getting an > Internal error,
`Could not validate caller for user "" when parsing`

```
- error_backtrace: ----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0xbcede5c0      1033  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_GET_ERROR
0xbcede5c0      1101  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_ADD_ERROR
0xbcede5c0      1493  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.RAISE_INTERNAL_ERROR
0xbcede5c0      1574  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.RAISE_MASKED_INTERNAL_ERROR
0xd11c9840       501  package body SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200.PARSE_AS_USER
0xd11d27f0      2006  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC.PARSE_AS_USER
0xd11d27f0      2513  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC.RUN_BLOCK5
0xd11d27f0      1301  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC.GET_PLSQL_EXPR_RESULT_BOOLEAN
0xbc8fef90       207  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_CONDITIONS.STANDARD_CONDITION
0xbcd71460        71  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_META_UTIL.IS_OK_TO_DISPLAY
0xbcd71460       118  package body APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_META_UTIL.IS_OK_T~ 
- component: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS Region1
```

when I call  a PL/SQL procedure before header on Page in Oracle Apex:

```
begin
  doSomething;
end;
```

The procedure has the CREATE_SESSION procedure in it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE doSomething
AS 
BEGIN

   apex_session.create_session (
    p_app_id   => 100,
    p_page_id  => 1,
    p_username => 'doSomething USER');

    insert into table1 (column1, column1) values (val1, val2);

   apex_session.delete_session (v('APP_SESSION'));

END;
```

The doSomething procedure seems to run fine as, after I get the Internal error, I can check table1  and see that data as correctly been inserted into the table.
My main problem now is getting the page to do something else like branch to a new modal but the Internal error is preventing that as nothing on the page renders, no regions, no buttons, nothing.

Is they a way to either fix the error or just bypass it altogether?
I've tried removing the component it supposedly has the issue with, but the same error comes back on a different component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a procedure from within apex, that procedure has the context of the current apex session. `create_session` is only needed outside of an APEX context, for example in code that is invoke from a scheduler job but that needs a session.

So what I suspect is happening is that the `apex_session.delete_session (v('APP_SESSION'));` is destroying the apex session you are correctly connected as in your application. Just get rid of any `apex_session` calls in your application or in any code called from your application.

Comment: Removing apex_session.delete_session (v('APP_SESSION'));, worked! So now I have remember to add it back, as I do plan on using the procedure as a scheduled job. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also remove the create session